# Why can a const method take a non const reference?

Tags: c++

I know a const method cannot modify the object from which it is called. Look at this code:

```
class A{
    int a;
    public:
        void f(A & a_) const {
        a_.a=5;
        };
};
int main(){
    A x;
    x.f(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code compile? Why can I even assign a reference to a non const object of the same class, when declaring the method as constant? In general how can the compiler check all the possible situations in which the function could modify the object?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't compile? The `const` applies to `this`, so long as nothing of `this` is being changed, it's fine. Note that `this` and the incoming `a` are _not_ considered to be the same.

Comment: The parameter to `f()` can be any object of the given type. There is no law that says that only `this` must be passed to it, as a parameter.

Comment: I suppose there could be potential for an aliasing violation.  If the `f` method was doing manipulation of `a_.a` and then comparing to its own `a` member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `const` member function cannot modify the object from which it is called *using the "implicit" `this` parameter*. `f(...)` is (ignoring member visibility) equivalent to the free function

```
void f(const A* this, A& _a) {
    _a.a = 5;
}
```

If you pass the same object as a non-const pointer or reference, you are still allowed to modify it.

Answer (score 7):

> I know a const method cannot modify the object from which it is called.

This is an oversimplification, and slightly inaccurate.

A `const` function merely means that the implicit `this` pointer is a pointer to `const`.

> Why does this code compile?

Because it is well-formed.

> Why can I even assign a reference to a non const object of the same class, when declaring the method as constant?

Because constness of the function does not affect what objects you can modify through a reference.

> In general how can the compiler check all the possible situations in which the function could modify the object?

The compiler simply does not make such checks.

Comment: Adding a section on `mutable` might also make sense.